# Is it possible to pass color schemes as parameters when launching vim ?

Tags: vim, parameters, colors, schema

I use VIM with different types of files, so each time I need to set specific color schemes.
Is it possible to pass them as parameters ?

Example:
    vim colorscheme=desert

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`vim -c "colorscheme desert" $file`

or equally

`vim +"colorscheme desert" $file`

Note: you can use any command, not only `colorscheme`. For more information, see [manpage](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/vim/).

Answer (score 5):

Another way is to use `autocomand` e.g. in your `.vimrc`

```
au BufEnter *.c  :colorscheme wombat
au BufEnter *.js :colorscheme desert
```